# Attempting to read in a string to put into a binary tree

Tags: c++, string, tree, binary-tree

I am trying to take a string and then manipulate it into a binary tree. The only problem is, I'm having a hard time actually reading in the strings. I know that in c++ each individual character is a char, not a string, but I can't figure out how to recurse through the string to get each char (I hope that made sense). I'm trying to put in the first char into my constructor as the root and then go into my build tree function which would then continue down the line populating it. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
class PrefixTree
{
    private:
        struct TreeNode
        {
            char character;
            TreeNode * left;
            TreeNode * right;
        };
        TreeNode* root = new TreeNode;
    public:

    PrefixTree(string value)
    {
        if (value == '*')
        {
            root->character = value;

        }
        buildTree(root, value);
    }
    TreeNode* buildTree(TreeNode* node, string value)
    {
        TreeNode* currentNode = new TreeNode;
        currentNode = node;

        if (currentNode->character == '*' && currentNode->left == NULL)
        {
            currentNode->left = buildTree(currentNode->right,value);
            return currentNode;
        }
        else if (currentNode->character == '*' && currentNode->right == NULL)
        {
            currentNode->right = buildTree(currentNode->right,value);
            return currentNode;
        }
        else
        {
            return currentNode;
        }
    }
```

and how I'm calling the constructor in main:

```
  PrefixTree n("*ab");
```

Comment: The 'TreeNode* currentNode = new TreeNode;
 currentNode = node;' at the start of buildTree must be wrong - you are first allocating a TreeNode and then overwriting the pointer with node, thus throwing away your newly allocated memory

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [] operator on strings to get individual characters.

For example:

```
string a = "hello";
cout << a[0];
```

Will print "h", the first character of a.

I would suggest, inside your recursive function, getting a character with the [] operator, then using the .substr() function to recurse on part of the string.